# Laravel logging System User fails

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

Im trying to log in a system user without sessions or cookies.

The following code in my middelware works unless the user id is from a system user:

```
   $interface_token = $request->header('token');

   if ($interface_token !== 'my_secret') {
        return response('Unauthorized', 401);
    }

    $user_id = 1; // Just for testing. Here I want to login a system user.

    $success = Auth::onceUsingId($user_id);

    if (!$success)
    {
        throw new Exception('failed!');
    }
```

I want to log in a system user since this specific routes are going to be call from an internal service not from a "real" user.

If I update the table users setting `system_user = 0` of user id 1, it works.

If `system_user = 1` then it doesn't authenticate.

This system_user column is just a tinyint added to the user's table that shouldn't affect but apparently it does.

The user model is using the SystemUserTrait.

Any ideas?

I'm using Laravel 5.4

### Edit

The SystemUserTrait is adding a global scope which does the following:

```
public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
{
    $builder->where('system_user', '=', 0);
}
```

So that's why it was not working with the user system. But now the question is if is possible to disable this to authenticate the user.

I tried the following without success:

```
  $user = User::withoutGlobalScope(SystemUser::class)->find(1);

  $success = Auth::login($user);
```

The user is fetched but the login fails anyway.

Is there a way to avoid using the global scope for a function?

Comment: Auth::loginUsingId($id); check the manual https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#login-throttling use once not onceUsingId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to fetch the user with `User::withoutGlobalScope` and then to use `Auth::setUser` function to avoid queries which used the scope.

```
$interface_token = $request->header('token');

if ($interface_token !== 'my_secret') {
    return response('Unauthorized', 401);
}

$user = User::withoutGlobalScope(SystemUser::class)->find(1);

Auth::setUser($user);
```